# Redis: Expire Values in a List or Set

Tags: redis, node-redis

Allow me to preface this by saying I'm fairly new to Redis. I have used Redis in the context of Resque.

I have a service that dispatches jobs to multiple other services. Those jobs either succeed or fail. Regardless of this, I'd like to send the results of what happened with a given job to a client that can then store they jobs in some sort of logical way, for example: JobType1Success, JobTypeOneFailure, etc.

I know I can create lists or sets with Redis and easily add some string representation of the data as values to the lists. Additionally, I know with traditional key/string values in Redis you can set an expiration in seconds. In my ideal world I would create several lists such as the ones mentioned above. Each job would then be prepended to it's appropriate list type, and after 7 days in the list a value would expire. Right now it seems fairly trivial to add the string values to a given list. However I am unable to find anything on whether or not I am able to expire values of a certain age from a list, and if so how to do that. I am working with a Node stack and using the Node Redis library. Any help here would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: Redis doesn't support expire element in list.